# Access of tables in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to see the access/permission of a table for a specific user or role? Didn't get much from documentation. Any help on providing the SQL would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
SHOW GRANTS ON TABLE schema.table;
```

Should work. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html